# change on the url latitude and longitude

Tags: php, javascript, url

i have one URL:- [Link](http://services.gisgraphy.com/geoloc/search?lat=43.00034713745117&lng=-75.4999008178711&radius=7000)
i want to change there lat and lng value 
i have one code to get region name and latitude and longitude value from IP address 
this is my code:-

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js" ></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                function load(){
                var region= geoip_city();
                var lan=geoip_latitude();
                var lng=geoip_longitude()
                    $('div').html(region)
                    alert(lan);
                    alert(lng);
                    }
        </script>
    <body onload="load()">
        <div></div>
    </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

with this code i have alert one latitude and longitude value.
i want to change on my given url link with this lat and lng value.

Comment: @scones i want to change latitude and longitude value in given url with my code display latitude and longitude value

Comment: Just do an AJAX call in that URL by replacing the lat/long in your code

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to your webpage using javascript.

```
window.location.replace('http://services.gisgraphy.com/geoloc/search?lat='+lan+'&lng='+lng+'&radius=7000');
```

or:

```
window.location.href = 'http://services.gisgraphy.com/geoloc/search?lat='+lan+'&lng='+lng+'&radius=7000';
```

**Update:**

Or, like Amit says, do an AJAX call with that vars